# For comprehensions Future and Either

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension, scala-2.12

I am struggling in how to compose a sequence of asynchronous processes in a nice monadic way. Each step of the process could fail so it is retrieving a `Future[Either[String, T]]`.

```
def firstStep(input: Int): Future[Either[String, Long]] = ???
def secondStep(input: Long): Future[Either[String, String]] = ???
def thirdStep(input: String): Future[Either[String, Double]] = ???
```

Given these functions I would like to compose them like this

```
def process(input: Int): Future[Either[String Double]] = {
     for{
        res1 <- firstStep(input)
        res2 <- secondStep(res1)
        res3 <- thirdStep(res2)
     } yield res3
}
```

But this doesn't work because each partial result is an `Either[String, T]`,and what I need is the `T` itself (or just stop the execution and return the `Left` if that's the case).

How can I compose this functions in a nice monadic way (using for-comprehensions)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `EitherT` monad transformer can help, either (pun intended) from cats or scalaz:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.EitherT

def process(input: Int): Future[Either[String, Double]] = {
   val res = for {
      res1 <- EitherT(firstStep(input))
      res2 <- EitherT(secondStep(res1))
      res3 <- EitherT(thirdStep(res2))
   } yield res3
   res.value
}
```

Comment: thanks, one question is this solution performing any kind of blocking over the futures?

Comment: @Mikel No. All of these calls are just `flatMap` and `map` calls on `EitherT`.